# Swift - Cannot convert value of type using generics

Tags: json, swift, generics

**How to fix this error?**

> Cannot convert value of type '(ApiContainer, *) -> ()' to
>   expected argument type '(ApiContainer<*>?, Error?) -> ()

[Screenshot showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mpDx.png)

**JSON response from the server:**

```
{
    "meta": {
        "sucess": "yes",
        "value": "123"
    },
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "Name 1",
            "postal_code": "PC1",
            "city": "City 1",
            "address": "01 Street"
        },
        {
            "name": "Name 2",
            "postal_code": "PC2",
            "city": "City 2",
            "address": "02 Street"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Structs**

```
struct Client: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let postal_code: String
    let city: String
}

struct Meta: Decodable {
    let sucess: String
    let value: String
}

struct ApiContainer<T: Decodable>: Decodable
    let meta: Meta
    let result: [T]
}
```

I have a function 'getAll' that is supposed to make a request and return the correspondent struct (ApiContainer where T can be for example Client)

```
func getAll() {
    makeRequest(endpoint: "http://blog.local:4711/api/all", completionHandler:
        {(response: ApiContainer<Client>, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error calling POST on /todos")
                print(error)
                return
            }
            print(result)

            //self.tableArray = decodedData.result

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } )
    }
```

Function makeRequest is called from getAll()

```
func makeRequest<T>(endpoint: String, completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        let error = BackendError.urlError(reason: "Could not create URL")
        completionHandler(nil, error)
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            completionHandler(nil, error!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiContainer<T>.self, from: responseData)
            completionHandler(response, nil)
        }
                catch {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    print(error)
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of generics you have to annotate the types in the closure explicitly to specify the static type of the generics

```
makeRequest(endpoint: "http://blog.local:4711/api/all", 
            completionHandler: { (container : ApiContainer<Client>?, error : Error?) in ...
```